# WGET command in putty console

Tags: linux, centos, vps

I am trying to run a wget command do download from a given list in background and if the file is arleady on disk to be overriten
 the command that try to use is :

```
wget -b -N -q -x -i liks.txt
```

But is not working. I am doing something wrong.?
I am running the command on a CENTOS VPS

Comment: What does it mean - 'not working'? Post here an error.

Comment: @Akarienta its not downloading nothing

Comment: Is some error displayed?

Comment: @Akarienta its telling that the process is running in background under PID21545 and thats all :)